# Mutlti level filter with search api and facet in commerce kickstart

Tags: commerce, search

I'm using commerce kickstart, I want to use the built-in filter blocks (facet & search-api).
I have multi-level categories (taxonomy), but filters just display parents categories.
For example I have as categories:

> computers
>   -laptops
>   -desktops
>   -notebook 
>   Networking
>   -routers
>   -modems

Filters just display computers and networking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to enable the "Expand Heierarcy" option under Facet Display settings (for the search index you are working with).

[image]